# Angular Change Detection and array.includes

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection, pure-function

Will this line be evaluated every time change detection runs even though the input is a hard-coded set of strings?

```
*ngSwitchCase="['abc', '123'].includes(item.field) ? "'test'" : ''"
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes

Here is the source of the ngSwitchCase showing it doOnCheck hook checks if value is true.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/47ab069070c043c54c46f8ef9b37b14a25857939/packages/common/src/directives/ng_switch.ts#L230

Comment: I'd also add that if you're using VS Code the extension "Angular Language Service" is very useful to identify what is interpreted as code visually.